# Issue with do - while loop ( javascript)

Tags: javascript, do-while

I am trying to create a loop where when a user presses a button the "+" sign is displayed on the screen but only once and it doesn't seem to work. I want it to display the "+" sign once when the button is clicked and then when the button is pressed again I don't want it to display unless I change the value of a to  true. can anyone help?

**The example below is just my entire code I am testing the aim to display the plus sign only once in the textfield**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function one()
        {document.frm.result.value +="1";}

        function three()
        {
         document.frm.result.value +="3";
        }

        function plus()
        {
            do{
                var a;
                document.frm.result.value = "+";

                var a = false;
               }while(a == 'true')
               }

        function evaluo()
        {
         var evalu = eval(document.frm.result.value);

            document.frm.result.value = evalu;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="button" value="2" name="2" onclick="dis()" id="test">
    <input type="button" value="3" name="3" onclick="three()" id="test3">
    <input type="button" value="+" name="plus" onclick="plus()" id="test2">
    <input type="button" value="evalu" onclick="evaluo()" id="e">


    <form name="frm">
    <input name="result">
    <div class="cal">
    <div id="left">
        <input type="text" value="" id="test1">

    <div id="bt1">1</div>
    <br>
    <div id="bt2">2</div>
    </div>

    <div id="cen">
        <div id="bt1">3</div>
    <br>
    <div id="bt2">4</div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div id="right">
        <div id="bt1" onclick="one()">35</div>
    <br>
    <div id="bt2">4</div>
    </div>

    </div>

    </div>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: What's that loop for? Please post a _working_ example, question isn't so clear now...

Comment: That loop knows only one iteration, so this code is basically the same as `document.frm.result.value += "+";` without all the other stuff.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the loop is for so that I can do 3+3 and NOT 3+3+3. I only want to be able to display the "+" sign once in a calculation. I have provided a an example. Sorry the code is a mess.

Comment: @user3115683 a loop is executed while condition is satisfied, you don't need it. BTW a == 'true' won't ever evaluate to true. Even if you write a == true then loop will be executed only once (then it's meaningless).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti can you suggest another solution for this issue?

Comment: Remove loop and add a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

The body of the loop will only execute once. After which control flow will move on to whatever code you have after this, or the calling function. You probably don't want to be using a loop for this, you just need a function which does `document.frm.result.value += "+";` and to call it whenever your button is clicked.

For example, if your function were called `displayPlus` then you could give your button an [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onclick) attribute like this: `<button onclick="displayPlus()">`

EDIT: It sounds like you want a way to decide conditionally whether to display another plus when the button is clicked. If you have logic that can determine whether this should be done at the time the button is pressed then this can be included in the function. For example if you want to only add another only if the previous character entered is not a plus then this method will work.

Otherwise you could have a global boolean variable and check its value whenever the plus button is clicked to determine whether to print another plus.

Comment: Hi, I did that but what I want is a loop which will let me control the amount of "+" signs it displays. Right now  it displays a "+" sign every time a button is pressed but I want to control that so when I press the button again it doesn't display the plus sign unless I change the condition of the loop.